# Updating a Rally.data.custom.Store

Tags: javascript, extjs, rally

I've create a Rally.data.custom.Store and used it to populate a Rally Grid.

Later (when some late queries come in), I change some of the records by getting the record object from the store and calling:

```
record.set(field, newValue);
```

This works like a champ, updating column hi lighting appropriately and all.  But when the user later resorts any column of the custom grid, all the records revert to their original values.

I've tried record.commit() and record.save() to no avail.  What am I missing?

Comment: Stay tuned... we haven't forgotten you. Rally's devs and app experts are engaged in a lively internal discussion about this one... ;-)

Comment: Looking forward to hearing your conclusion

Comment: Is this fixed yet? Im still having the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is a defect with the Rally.data.custom.Store code. I will file it so that we can address it when we get a chance.

Thanks for taking the time to help us test out the preview version of our new SDK.

Comment: Im having this issue with a rallygrid, is the defect fixed yet?